# Fabric sdk drop/drop breaking project during build

Tags: ios, uikit, twitter-fabric

I followed through the integration process of Fabric to my iOS application, however in the final step on dragging/dropping the fabric SDK into my application, once I dropped the fabric file, it breaks my project. The errors are:

"Could not build module 'UIKit'" for random files (ie everytime I build the project again, it breaks another file's import of UIKit)

The same thing for UIKit happens for QuartzCore.

One insight I had was that these were all frameworks that for some reason were breaking, but I am not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the problem, but I think I remember the Fabric integration tutorial telling me on that step where you drag the Framework to either not copy the items in the Xcode file import screen, or not to add it to a specific target when importing. Again, not sure if this could be causing it but it might be worth a look.

Comment: This did not help. It was defaulted to not copying the files. Moreover, if I did not add it to a target, it was OK (ie it build). However, obviously the I could not import the header files, so I eventually had to add the crashlytics framework to the project, but this broke the build :(